# Find DST timestamps between two timestamps

Tags: vba, windows

Is there any way to know all DST adjustment timestamps and offset between two time stamp?
If there are more then one DST adjustment, I want both timestamps and offset for all instances. By bias here I mean if clock went forward by 1 hours offset=60 and if clock went back by 1 hours offset=-60

For ex.

```
Time Zone: Pacific Time (UTC -8:00)
Start Time: 1 Nov 2020 0:00:00
End Time: 4 Nov 2020 0:00:00
Result: 1 Nov 2020 2:00:00 And Offset of -60 Minutes
```

Comment: Google "vba dst adjustments", takes you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248506/vba-local-timezone-adjustment/21248705).

Comment: @HansPassant This is for current date only, I have to iterate for all days between start and end time if I want to use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `BiasWindowsTimezone` (below) from my project [VBA.Timezone-Windows](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Timezone-Windows):

```vb
StartTime = #2020/11/01 00:00:00#
EndTime = #2020/11/04 00:00:00#
BiasDiff = BiasWindowsTimezone("Pacific", True, StartTime) - BiasWindowsTimezone("Pacific", True, EndTime)
BiasDiff  -> -60
```

Demo applications for *Excel* and *Access* are included. If you run the Excel application, be sure first to call the function `ReloadTimezones` to create the worksheet with the data.

```vb
' Returns the timezone bias as specified in Windows from
' the name (key) of a timezone entry in the Registry.
' Accepts values without the common trailing "Standard Time".
'
' If Dst is true, and the current date is within daylight saving time,
' bias for daylight saving time is returned.
' If Date1 is specified, the bias of that date is returned.
'
' Returns a bias of zero if a timezone is not found.
'
' Examples:
'   Bias = BiasWindowsTimezone("Argentina")
'   Bias -> 180     ' Found
'
'   Bias = BiasWindowsTimezone("Argentina Standard Time")
'   Bias -> 180     ' Found.
'
'   Bias = BiasWindowsTimezone("Germany")
'   Bias -> 0       ' Not found.
'
'   Bias = BiasWindowsTimezone("Western Europe")
'   Bias -> 0       ' Not found.
'
'   Bias = BiasWindowsTimezone("W. Europe")
'   Bias -> -60     ' Found.
'
'   Bias = BiasWindowsTimezone("Paraguay", True, #2018-07-07#)
'   Bias -> 240     ' Found.
'
'   Bias = BiasWindowsTimezone("Paraguay", True, #2018-02-11#)
'   Bias -> 180     ' Found. DST.
'
'   Bias = BiasWindowsTimezone("Paraguay", False, #2018-02-11#)
'   Bias -> 240     ' Found.
'
' 2018-11-16. Gustav Brock. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function BiasWindowsTimezone( _
    ByVal TimezoneName As String, _
    Optional Dst As Boolean, _
    Optional Date1 As Date) _
    As Long
    
    Static Entries()    As TimezoneEntry
    Static LastName     As String
    Static LastYear     As Integer
    
    Static Entry        As TimezoneEntry
    Dim ThisName        As String
    Dim ThisYear        As Integer
    Dim StandardDate    As Date
    Dim DaylightDate    As Date
    Dim DeltaBias       As Long
    Dim Bias            As Long
    
    If Trim(TimezoneName) = "" Then
        ' Nothing to look up.
        Exit Function
    Else
        ThisName = Trim(TimezoneName)
        ThisYear = Year(Date1)
        If LastName = ThisName And LastYear = ThisYear Then
            ' Use cached data.
        Else
            ' Retrieve the single entry or - if not found - an empty entry.
            Entries = RegistryTimezoneItems(ThisName, (ThisYear))
            Entry = Entries(LBound(Entries))
            LastName = ThisName
            LastYear = ThisYear
        End If
        If _
            StrComp(Entry.Name, TimezoneName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Or _
            StrComp(Replace(Entry.Name, StandardTimeLabel, ""), TimezoneName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            ' Windows timezone found.
            
            ' Default is standard bias.
            DeltaBias = Entry.Tzi.StandardBias
            If Dst = True Then
                ' Return daylight bias if Date1 is of daylight saving time.
                StandardDate = DateSystemTime(Entry.Tzi.StandardDate)
                DaylightDate = DateSystemTime(Entry.Tzi.DaylightDate)
                
                If DaylightDate < StandardDate Then
                    ' Northern Hemisphere.
                    If DateDiff("s", DaylightDate, Date1) >= 0 And DateDiff("s", Date1, StandardDate) > 0 Then
                        ' Daylight time.
                        DeltaBias = Entry.Tzi.DaylightBias
                    Else
                        ' Standard time.
                    End If
                Else
                    ' Southern Hemisphere.
                    If DateDiff("s", DaylightDate, Date1) >= 0 Or DateDiff("s", Date1, StandardDate) > 0 Then
                        ' Daylight time.
                        DeltaBias = Entry.Tzi.DaylightBias
                    Else
                        ' Standard time.
                    End If
                End If
                
            End If
            ' Calculate total bias.
            Bias = Entry.Bias + DeltaBias
        End If
    End If

    BiasWindowsTimezone = Bias

End Function
```